# Keeping Firefox from adding ".html" to url

Tags: firefox, browser, apache-http-server, htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've been messing with `.htaccess` for a while, and have the following rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(mypage|myotherpage)/?$ main.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]
```

If I enter http://mydomain.com/mypage/, it displays main.php as desired.

If I enter http://mydomain.com/mypage (note the lacking trailing backslash), it redirects to http://mydomain.com/mypage.html, and obviously displays a 404 Not Found error.  I've tried this same URL using Chrome on the same PC, and it doesn't add the `.html`.  I've also tried the same URL on FireFox on another PC, and again it doesn't add the `.html`.

Earlier when messing with `.htaccess`, I had rules which added `.html` to the URL.  I've since gotten rid of these rules, but wonder if FF somehow buffered them?

Any thoughts?  Thanks

Comment: Have you tried handling this through the DirectoryIndex?
> DirectoryIndex main.php index.html

Comment: @quickcel.  No, I haven't.  I deleted all browsing history from FF, and it seems to no longer do so.  Maybe that is all it takes?

Comment: Yes, this sounds like a browser _cache_ problem (not _history_). The browser should never simply add `.html` to a URL - that would be a serious fault of the browser. Browsers do cache _external redirects_ (such as 301 redirects). However, the code you posted above is an internal rewrite - the browser would not cache this as it doesn't see it.

Comment: @w3d.  I had previous used rules such as `RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [R=301,L]`.  Maybe the culprit?

Comment: That was probably it! FWIW I've found Opera to hold on to its cache even more than Firefox - quite a problem sometimes when you're trying to test things.

Comment: @w3d.  Yes, it does cause havoc when testing!

Comment: @user1032531 You might want to convert your comments into an answer ;)